# How to Access AWS AppConfig in .Net Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-app-config

I want to access config files from AWS AppConfig in .Net Core (AWS Lambda). How can I do that? I have seen in the AWS docs that the recommended way is to use the GetLatestConfiguration and StartConfigurationSession APIs but I am unable to find the functions in AWS .Net Client SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working by using `AWSSDK.AppConfigData` nuget package.

Note that examples out on the web you may find make it difficult to find it due to the namespace changing from the deprecated version.

I want to emphasize again that the sdk is `AWSSDK.AppConfigData` and not the deprecated `AWSSDK.AppConfig`.

Once the package is installed you can leverage the sdk with:

> using Amazon.AppConfigData;
> using Amazon.AppConfigData.Model

Client model is called `AmazonAppConfigDataClient`
once you initialize the client you can call `StartConfigurationSessionAsync` which accepts a model of `StartConfigurationSessionRequest` and will return a `StartConfigurationSessionResponse`

You can then use the client to call `GetLatestConfigurationAsync`

`GetLatestConfigurationAsync` will accept a model of `GetLatestConfigurationRequest`. You can populate its `InitialConfigurationToken` property with from the `StartConfigurationSessionResponse.InitialConfigurationToken` you get back from your session call.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.  I was using the deprecated version.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to do this is using the App Config Lambda extension. The link below provides further detail, but the extension simplifies a lot of the communication between your function and AppConfig whilst also providing an element of caching and cost reduction.

From your perspective, you then interact with AppConfig by making requests to a local web endpoint
*(http://localhost:2772/applications/application_name/environments/environment_name/configurations/configuration_name)*

Full details can be found below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-integration-lambda-extensions.html